# Redirecting to a response view with a model does not keep model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore8

I have a form view that submits form data to the post action on a controler and then redirects to another view that uses logic to display either a success or failure, but the new view just shows blank values for model properties.  Here is the post action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactUs(TTT.Models.ContactUsModel model)
    {
        logger.Info(model.URL + "Contact Us Form submitted");

        var userkey = model.ValidationKey;
        var sessionkey = Session["ContactUsKey"];
        var lastsubmission = Session["ContactUsTime"];
        model.Response = "success";

        //first check if honeypot was populated via a bot and if so send it to the success page without doing anything
        if (model.WorkAddress != "")
        {
            logger.Info("honeypot triggered");
            return View("ContactUsResponse", model);
        }
```

I'll leave out the remainder of the controler, but

And here is the view it's redirecting to:

```
@using TTT.Models
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@model ContactUsModel


 <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
 <div>@Model.Body</div>

  <div>
     @if (@Model.Response == "fail")
      {
          @Model.Failure;
      } else
      {
          @Model.Success;
      }
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a new view, call `RedirectToAction` and return new view from that controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactUs(TTT.Models.ContactUsModel model)
{
    //--- Code omitted for brevity

    if (model.WorkAddress != "")
    {
        logger.Info("honeypot triggered");
        return RedirectToAction("ContactUsResponse", new { response = model });
    }
}

public ActionResult ContactUsResponse(TTT.Models.ContactUsModel response) 
{
    return View(model)
}
```